# Auto dismiss popup like Tweetbot iOS app

Tags: ios, uiview, cocoapods

Is any Cocoa Pod I can use to implement a auto dismiss popup like <del>Instagram's</del> Tweetbot's as below?

Or I need to do it by myself by inheriting from UIView?

Thanks

[image: A network error popup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot you show is actually from Tweetbot, but assuming that is really what you want, I've used this class with much success:

https://github.com/tciuro/NoticeView

[image]

via [CocoaControls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/noticeview)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that why I didn't get the result from Google. Why I thought that's from Instagram because I read that from [this presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/mikeyk/secrets-to-lightning-fast-mobile-design) by Mike Krieger who is the  co-founder of Instagram. Thanks for your correction.

Comment: Not being able to hear the presentation (only see the slides), I wonder if he is comparing/contrasting different ways of failure notification between Instagram and Tweetbot

Comment: yes, slides only, can't find the video/audio. I think he took Tweetbot's failure notification as a good example, I can't find any Instagram failure message screens in the slides.